# Google Test - test fails only in mode release and using ASSERT_*

Tags: c++, debugging, release, googletest, assertions

I am using Google Test in my project, and I'm used to using ASSERT macros (ASSERT_EQ, ASSERT_STREQ, etc.) rather than EXPECT to stop my test at first fail.

I usually test my project in debug mode, everything goes find, no problem is detected with Valgrind (no memory leak, no bad access).

Recently, I tested my code in release mode (flag -O3 for optimization), and some of my tests keep failing. However, as soon as I replace all ASSERT_* by EXPECT_* (which is supposed to be the non-terminating assertion), all my tests pass perfectly.

My questions are:

- Are ASSERT_* macros of gtest suitable for high-level code optimization? Or is it 100% sure the issue is in my code?
- If the issue is in my code, what could make EXPECT_* macros pass and not ASSERT_*?

I'm sorry this post has no reproducible code, but a dozen files with thousands lines would be necessary to copy.

Comment: My guess is that (A) Your tests are not independent enough. (B) You code with potential UB that the optimizer takes advantage of. And when things aren't done in a very specific way (such as when `ASSERT_*` prevents cleanup), your tests fail.

Comment: @StoryTeller What do you mean by "not independent enough" ?

Comment: Meaning that a possible test_2 depends on some, however small, work that is done be test_1 that runs before it.

Comment: Remove tests until you can't reproduce the described discrepancy, thereby isolating the offending test.